Can we find a "s", "t" parametrization of any planar simple curve?
Let
$$r: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^{2}, $$
be a simple curve. Denote by $\Omega$ the interior of the curve defined by $r(t)$. Without loss of generality, let us assume that $(0,0) \in \Omega$.
Does there exist a family of maps $(r_s(t))_{0\leq s \leq 1} : \mathbb{R} \to \bar{\Omega}$ (the closure) that is continuous in $s$ such that...

$r_{0}(t) = r(t)$, $r_{1}(t) = (0,0)$,
$r_{s}(t)$ is also a simple curve
The map $r(s,t) \to r_s(t)$ is bijective, except possibly $r(s,0) = r(s,1)$ and $r(1,t) = (0,0)$.

If the region is star shaped and $(0,0)$ is in the region all edges can see, I believe that choosing the linear interpolation $r_s(t) = (1-s)r(t)$ works. However, in the event that $(0,0)$ does not see all of the curve, I do not believe this works. The goal here is to parametrize the region $\bar{\Omega}$ in $s,t$ with unique coordinates except at the endpoints.
For an example where linear interpolation fails, take the image below.

Linearly interpolating between any of the sharp corners and $(0,0)$ will violate the condition that the image of $r(s,t)$ is in $\bar{\Omega}$, as it will cross outside $\bar{\Omega}$.

You are talking about a hyperplane in $\Bbb R^n$, yet you seem to be thinking about a $2$-dimensional affine plane.

How can you add a number ($\xi\cdot x$) and an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($h$)?

Apologies, having read these comments I mixed up my wording. @TedShifrin is correct and I mean a 2-dimensional affine plane. I will reword this.

Your definition is still flawed. The condition $r([0,1]) \subset \lbrace \xi \cdot x = c : x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \rbrace$ does not says that the curve lies on a plane.

Note aside, you wrote $r([0,1)]$ instead of $r([0,1])$

@jjagmath This is what I get for assuming that this dot product defaults to a $2d$ plane from sticking to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ so often... I've instead opted to rewrite it as an 2d affine plane as Ted wrote earlier.

Your whole question is about something happening on the plane that contains the curve, so it makes no sense to set the problem in $\Bbb R^n$. Just consider a curve $r:[0,1]\to \Bbb R^2$ and state your problem there.

What you're talking about is a homotopy between your mapping and a constant mapping. A plane is contractible, so it always exists. In particular, consider $r_s(t) = (1-s)r(t)+s\mathbf y$.

The main issue with just taking a homotopy for me is that the particular one given doesn't necessarily stay in the region bounded by the original simple curve. I've since modified my question to try and improve it @TedShifrin as per the recommendation of jjagmath.

Since the curve can be quite horrible, I’m afraid you’re going to have to apply the Jordan Curve Theorem to conclude — in the abstract — that the curve bounds a topological disk.

I think actually this question will require the full Jordan-Schönflies theorem. @TedShifrin

@LeeMosher Yes, I was just too lazy typing on my iPad. I totally agree. If the curve is sufficiently smooth (and the image is a sufficiently smooth submanifold), then it's an easier and more geometric result. See, for example, Guillemin & Pollack.

@TedShifrin This is more than a homotopy between the curve and the constant. The OP is asking that each stage of the homotopy to be simple curves.
